# how to remove star(*) from date as a Regex match Group T1 output

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In below regex check and match groups, `T1` output is `*May 13 01:16:14.736`.

I would like to remove start (*) from the output (`May 13 01:16:14.736`), whats change is required in Regex expression?

```
var input = @": *May 13 01:16:14.736 UTC: %XYZ";
        var regex = new Regex(@":\s+(?<T1>.*)UTC:\s%+(?<T2>.*)");
        //var regex = new Regex(@":\s*+(?<T1>.*)UTC:\s%+(?<T2>.*)");
        var match = regex.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["T1"]);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["T2"]);
        }
```

I tried below expression, but getting exception,

```
var regex = new Regex(@":\s*+(?<T1>.*)UTC:\s%+(?<T2>.*)");
```

Comment: you familiar with `.Replace()` function? have you done a google search on how to Replace strings or characters

Comment: Is the star always there?  If so just match it outside of the capture group.  Note you'll have to escape it like `@":\s+\*(?<T1>.*)UTC:\s+%(?<T2>.*)"`.

Comment: @MethodMan, I don't want to use `replace` or `trim` function. I m looking if anything is possible with Regex expression

Comment: Thanks @juharr 2. escape works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:\s+\*(?<T1>.*)UTC:\s%+(?<T2>.*)
```

Take a look at the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/aAowXI/2)...

Comment: Edited, sorry !

Comment: Glad to hear it. It was just a matter of taking the star symbol outside of the first matching group. If you compare the regular expressions you will notice the difference is very small.